# How to render alt and title texts of image file entities using a theme function

Tags: theming, media, files

Out of the box, image file entities have alt and title text fields attached, `field_file_image_alt_text` and `field_file_image_title_text` respectively, that provide the rendered image with an HTML alt and title text.

Today I feel like `Mysite.com` would be a great title for the images on my website, and I could easily programatically populate both text fields with `Mysite.com` upon upload of the image file. However, what if tommorrow I change my mind and instead of `Mysite.com` I want the alt and title text to be `Welcome to Mysite.com`? I would have to edit all file entities and modify both text fields for each.

Is there a way to render the alt and title text through a theming function so that I do not have to actually store the alt and title text within each file entity? I want to be able to modify the alt and title texts of *all* images by just modifying a *single* line of code.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is pretty easy, you can just preprocess `theme_image()`:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image(&$vars) {
  $vars['attributes']['alt'] = 'alt';
  $vars['attributes']['title'] = 'title';
}
```

If you're using any of the standard image display formatters they'll eventually be passed through `theme_image()` so that should work for all fields.

I'd strongly advise you consider **not** doing this though. The point of an alt tag is to describe the image to parties who can't interpret it in its original form (visually impaired people, robots, text only browsers, search engines, etc)

By setting the alt for every image to the same string, you're making your site quite inaccessible to those groups of visitors. And since Google and others assign a reasonable weight to alt text, you won't be doing your SEO any favours either.

Comment: I was simplifying my question. I want to load a submitted title (from a form field) and the author's username to build a custom alt and title text.

Comment: Ah ok that makes more sense, the above method along with the logic to combine the username with the saved var should do the trick

Comment: I will test it immediately, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, the alt and title text doesn't change when I add the function to my template.php. Is it possible that file entities' built-in alt and title functionality overrides the preprocess function?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get around this issue?